# Data hub setup for a structured wiring panel

Tags: ethernet, wiring

I have a structure wiring panel in my home and the bedrooms and living room all have ethernet jacks. All the coaxial cables in the panel are labelled as: 1, 2, 3, fp1, fp2, and 2 cables called emarc ).

[image]

I understand all the lables except emarc; for example, 1 = master bedroom, 2 and 3 are guest bedrooms, fp1 and fp2 are fireplace 1 and fireplace 2, but what does emarc stand for, is this a common abbreviation? The two coaxial cables that are labeled emarc are secured together with a tie.

1. Are these the two cables that are connected outside to Comcast?

I have been reading on how to set up the wiring panel so that I can make all the ethernet outlets live. All the cables that come through to the structured wiring panel have rj45 ends except for one and this cable is also labelled emarc.

[image]

All the data termination hubs I have been able to find have the 110 punch down connectors and the rj45 ports; that is, I would run cables from the router to the rj45 ports on the data hub and then tie in the cables running to the panel via the punch downs (see screenshot from OpenHouse manual).

[image]

One hub I have been looking at is the [OpenHouse Data Termination Hub](http://www.homecontrols.com/OpenHouse-Data-Termination-Hub-LNH628). However, if it is common to punch down the lines running through the house why would rj45 ends be put on the ethernet cables? Now this leads me to wondering about the cable without the rj45 end labelled emarc. Is there a termination hub that would allow a line in (emarc line punch down) that feeds rj45 ports (plug in lines with rj45)?

If there is a data hub that works like my thought above, please let me know as well. If not, any information on how I would configure this setup is welcome.

Comment: Could emark be missing a leading character?  "Demark" might make sense here. That being said, this question is off topic here

Answer (score 1):

Coaxial cables are used for signals ranging in Microwave region hence are studied as [Microwave transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_transmission),I think you are using a common connection for the TV and the DSL Router called cable connection ,The Tv signal is separated using a splitter, there are many types of splitter,you can just google them.for more information have a look at the [cable modem termination system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_modem_termination_system)

To make it simple I would say that the internet connection works usually on a Digital Subscriber Line [( DSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_subscriber_line),and your Tv set up Box works on the microwave signal,but I still don't get the whole system usually we use a paraboloid antenna also called the DISH through which signal are received in Microwave range and the demodulated to get message signal,but you have not stated which type of Tv connection you are using I assume it to be [CATV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_television)

You haven't really marked the emarc line in the block diagram I may change the answer if you do so.
The only thing I could Decode from the figure was:
All the Ports in the router are female RJ45
The First picture looks of the Splitter and filter combined.